# How do you achieve a fixed/fluid layout with CSS?

Tags: html, css

Look at the stackoverflow site - the screen adjusts width by decreasing the margins, until there are no margins, when the site becomes fixed. How can this be done?

Comment: You're probably looking for: `margin: 0 auto`

Comment: Read about Responsive Web Design (which StackOverflow does not use)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page is just centered, I believe. I would just contain all elements on the page with one div tag with a fixed width (of say 800px). Then, I would center it with `margin: 0 auto;`

```
#all {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the case of stackoverflow, it is just a fixed width in the centre of the screen, to achieve this you want to have a div for content that is a specified width, e.g. 960px is quite popular, then you position it with css `left:50%; margin-left:-480px;`  where 480 is half the width of the content.  I've found this to be more robust then margin: 0 auto;

if you want a site that really adjusts for the size of the browser window, do a bit of googleing for 'responsive web design' and 'css media queries', they should help you out.